# Range not working with Excel table using Autofilter from checkbox criteria

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, autofilter

What I'm trying to do is use a multiple checkbox form to set filter values based on a table in my "Projects" worksheet.  I've been able to successfully get this working on individuals however what I need this to do is take any combination of currently 33 checkboxes to filter rows that meet all criteria selected.  Below is what I currently have and it keep kicking back on the range. My range runs columns K:AQ which equal values of 11 to 43 as you'll see below.

```
Private Sub FilterButton_Click()

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook 
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Projects")
Dim fld As Long
For fld = 11 To 43
Next

If frmSearch.CheckBox1 = True = True Or _
frmSearch.CheckBox2 = True Or frmSearch.CheckBox3 = True Or _
frmSearch.CheckBox4 = True Or frmSearch.CheckBox5 = True Or _
frmSearch.CheckBox6 = True Or frmSearch.CheckBox7 = True Or _
frmSearch.CheckBox8 = True Or frmSearch.CheckBox9 = True Or _
frmSearch.CheckBox10 = True Or frmSearch.CheckBox11 = True Or _
frmSearch.CheckBox12 = True Or frmSearch.CheckBox13 = True Or _
frmSearch.CheckBox14 = True Or frmSearch.CheckBox15 = True Or _
frmSearch.CheckBox16 = True Or frmSearch.CheckBox17 = True Or _
frmSearch.CheckBox18 = True Or frmSearch.CheckBox19 = True Or _
frmSearch.CheckBox20 = True Or frmSearch.CheckBox21 = True Or _
frmSearch.CheckBox22 = True Or frmSearch.CheckBox23 = True Or _
frmSearch.CheckBox24 = True Or frmSearch.CheckBox25 = True Or _
frmSearch.CheckBox26 = True Or frmSearch.CheckBox27 = True Or _
frmSearch.CheckBox28 = True Or frmSearch.CheckBox29 = True Or _
frmSearch.CheckBox30 = True Or frmSearch.CheckBox31 = True Or _
frmSearch.CheckBox32 = True Or frmSearch.CheckBox33 = True Then

ws.Range("K2:AQ1500").AutoFilter Field:="fld", Criteria1:="<>"

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the quotes around `fld`, it's a variable not an actual string. Also the field number is relative, e.g. K would be column 1 in your autofilter range.

Comment: This removed the error, however it returns no value through the filter.  I'll see if I can get it to work.  Thank you!

Comment: Ok, for some reason if I modify my field value to 12 for instance, it will select the 12th column in the table.  I changed my fld variable back to 11 to 43 however now I get the range error again although it's only the field I've changed.  I'll keep working on this and update if I can find a solution.  If you have any ideas please let me know.  Thanks

Comment: Your range is 33 columns wide so your loop needs to run from 1 to 33.

Comment: When I set it up that way I can run without errors however it selects nothing.

Comment: If you look at your code it doesn't actually do anything except filter so your loop will not produce anything as such. It will filter K, L etc but that's it.

Comment: That's all I want it to do however it's not applying the filters properly.  In fields (K:AQ) I have anywhere from 1-33 assembly types.  I have a form that applies the assembly data from a list of checkboxes on input. My goal is to use a separate form with checkboxes that replicate the input to filter my table showing only "projects" that meet the checkbox selection criteria.  So for instance I may have 5 projects with the same 6 items on my assembly.  I would like to check the boxes and filter the 5 projects based on input from the assembly columns, ie (K:AQ)

Comment: Your code currently runs if any one of the checkboxes is true. I don't see the point of your code as it stands. Perhaps you should start again and take another crack at explaining what your code doesn't do that you want it to do.

Comment: Correct, so the goal is if any one or combination of the 33 checkboxes are selected I want the filter to run based on that checkbox to filter the value checked.  Columns K:AQ (11:43) correspond to checkbox 1-33 respectively.  Therefore if I have checkbox 1 and checkbox 28 selected i want my table to be filtered to where values are not blank in fields K and AL which are the 11th and 38th columns in my list.

Comment: This is why I tried setting the fld variable from 11-43 because those are the cells I'm actually referring to. I understand that they are relative to my range however when I set from 1-33 it returns nothing as the fld variable when I filter.  When I change the fld variable in the Autofilter line to any single value from 11-43 however, it performs perfectly on just that one value.  So in this case, if I set (Field:=11), when I run my command it will return all values in column K that are not blank.

Comment: This is perfect however I need it to run this way on any combination of selections from the original checkbox selection.  Please let me know if this is still unclear.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: So you want to filter the column corresponding to any checkbox that is ticked? I think you'd have to build an array of the checkbox numbers and then filter those columns with a loop. Not sure if that makes sense. I'll take a look later if not.

Answer (score 1):

So I don't know what your UserForm looks like, but if you can, I would suggest moving these CheckBoxes to a Frame so you can loop through them much easier... like this:

```
Private Sub FilterButton_Click()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Projects")

    Dim i As Integer

    ' For each child control in the frame
    For i = 0 To Frame1.Controls.Count - 1

        ' If the child control is a check box
        If TypeOf Frame1.Controls.Item(i) Is CheckBox Then

            ' If the CheckBox is checked
            If Frame1.Controls.Item(i).Value Then

                 'Your code here...
                 Debug.Print (i & " " & Frame1.Controls.Item(i).Name)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

As for applying the filter, it sounds like each checkbox should be linked to a column in your range... (meaning Checkbox1 ==> 'K'?) I would do that like this: (replacing the 'your code here' from above)

```
' Add a filter to the column at the index of 'i' (+1 so we aren't using base 0)
ws.Range("K2:AQ1500").AutoFilter Field:=i + 1, Criteria1:="<>"
```

Please, if you don't understand the code, ask! I'm more than happy to explain anything. Remember that copy/paste doesn't teach! :D

Answer (score 0):

Does your code not have too many "True" at the `If frmSearch.CheckBox1 = True = True`
part?

Try below.

```
Private Sub FilterButton_Click()

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook 
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Projects")
Dim fld As Long
For fld = 11 To 43
Next

If frmSearch.CheckBox1 = True Or _
frmSearch.CheckBox2 = True Or frmSearch.CheckBox3 = True Or _
frmSearch.CheckBox4 = True Or frmSearch.CheckBox5 = True Or _
frmSearch.CheckBox6 = True Or frmSearch.CheckBox7 = True Or _
frmSearch.CheckBox8 = True Or frmSearch.CheckBox9 = True Or _
frmSearch.CheckBox10 = True Or frmSearch.CheckBox11 = True Or _
frmSearch.CheckBox12 = True Or frmSearch.CheckBox13 = True Or _
frmSearch.CheckBox14 = True Or frmSearch.CheckBox15 = True Or _
frmSearch.CheckBox16 = True Or frmSearch.CheckBox17 = True Or _
frmSearch.CheckBox18 = True Or frmSearch.CheckBox19 = True Or _
frmSearch.CheckBox20 = True Or frmSearch.CheckBox21 = True Or _
frmSearch.CheckBox22 = True Or frmSearch.CheckBox23 = True Or _
frmSearch.CheckBox24 = True Or frmSearch.CheckBox25 = True Or _
frmSearch.CheckBox26 = True Or frmSearch.CheckBox27 = True Or _
frmSearch.CheckBox28 = True Or frmSearch.CheckBox29 = True Or _
frmSearch.CheckBox30 = True Or frmSearch.CheckBox31 = True Or _
frmSearch.CheckBox32 = True Or frmSearch.CheckBox33 = True Then

ws.Range("K2:AQ1500").AutoFilter Field:="fld", Criteria1:="<>"

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It does, but I think it should still evaluate to TRUE.

Comment: I corrected the duplicate True however I still get error 1004 "Autofilter Method of Range Class Failed." Thank you for catching that though.  I've been staring at this far too long.